# Is Async-CTP(AsyncCtpLibrary.dll) official supported?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Visual Studio Async CTP could be [downloaded](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=9983), and there is documentation about **async**, **wait** features.. But I still don't see these in VS2013, .NET 4.5. I can install it because I have 2010 on my machine too, but I don't understand if it is still not official supported in 2015? So I should not use these features in my projects?..

Comment: Umm, all of the async and await stuff is built in to VS2013, you don't need some library to do it. Can you explain more about what you mean when you say *"But I still don't see these in VS2013"*

Comment: The Async CTP was a prerelease version of the async/await feature. This feature has long been part of C# (since VS2012), so you don't need the Async CTP anymore.

Comment: Cool. I used it wrong and thought that if intellisence does not recognize it, is not included. Thank You! :)